# magento based on discount application tax calculation?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, discount

I have added one product to cart that price is 495 we are displaying product price including tax.but we are displaying subtotal exclude tax.

```
Product (V)             495.00
Sub-total               471.43
VAT @ 5%                23.57
Total                   495.00
```

The above tax calculating the sub total.That is default it is fine...

**the tax for 471.43 vat is 23.57**

But My aim is after applied discount i want calculate tax is not an subtotal i want to calculate total..

```
Product (V)           495.00
Sub-total             495.00
Discount              49.50 (minus)
VAT @ 5%              21.21
Total                 445.50
```

After discount apply i need to calculate vat i mean second one tax is 21.21.
**tax is calculating 445.50**

How can I customize this in Magento

Comment: in config > sales > tax there is an option Apply tax after/before discount, you can change it there

Comment: it is ok but two differ ways i need after discount tax calculation is diifer before discount tax calculation is differ